# Ansible script ssh error

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, ansible, ssh-keys

I am creating a vm in openstack (linux vm) and launching ansible script from there.I am getting following ssh error.

```
---
- hosts: licproxy
  user: my-user  
  sudo: yes
  tasks:

  - name: Install tinyproxy#
    command: sudo apt-get install tinyproxy

  - name: Update tinyproxy
    command: sudo apt-get update

  - name: Install bind9
    shell: yes '' | sudo apt-get install bind9
```

Though I am directly able to ssh to machine 10.32.1.40 from the linux box in openstack admin-keydev29

```
  PLAY [licproxy] ***********************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
<10.32.1.40> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: my-user
<10.32.1.40> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<10.32.1.40> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentityFile="/opt/apps/installer/tenant-dev29/ssh/admin-key-dev29" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=my-user -o ConnectTimeout=10 10.32.1.40 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1450797442.33-90087292637238 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1450797442.33-90087292637238 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1450797442.33-90087292637238'
EXEC previous known host file not found for 10.32.1.40
fatal: [10.32.1.40] => SSH Error: ssh: connect to host 10.32.1.40 port 22: Connection refused
    while connecting to 10.32.1.40:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.

TASK: [Install tinyproxy] *****************************************************
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I removed from known_host entry and ran the script again it is still showing me same message.

**UPDATE**

I observed manual ssh is working fine.but ansible script is giving ssh error.
I logged in to the newly created vm using ssh key and checked /var/log/auth.log file

```
Dec 30 13:00:33 licproxy-vm sshd[1184]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Dec 30 13:01:10 licproxy-vm sshd[1448]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Dec 30 13:01:10 licproxy-vm sshd[1448]: Connection closed by 192.168.0.106 [preauth]
Dec 30 13:01:32 licproxy-vm sshd[1450]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

The vm has sshd version OpenSSH_6.6.1 version
I checked /etc/ssh folder i found ssh_host_ed25519_key and ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub missing

I created those file using command ssh-keygen -A.

Now I want to know why these files are missing from ssh folder.Is this a bug?

Comment: IP whitelist on the server maybe?

Comment: @eugecm...Whats that ?

Comment: Can you connect directly from the machine you're using ansible with?

Comment: @eugecm yes i am able to connect

Comment: Can you add -vvvv to the command and post the output on the question ?

Comment: What is your ansible version?

Comment: 1.9.3...I have given the -vvvv output in the question

Comment: Focus on this error: EXEC previous known host file not found for 10.32.1.40

Can you check ~my-user/.ssh/known_hosts file exists?

Comment: @helloV yes it exist ...i ran command ssh-keygen -R 10.32.1.40...but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was because of ssh port 22.The port was not up.
I added the following code.which basically wait for ssh port to come up.

```
while ! nc -z $PROXY_SERVER_IP 22; do
  sleep 10s
done
```